# When using bracket with a Ptr as resource, can it be replaced with ForeignPtr?

Tags: haskell, ffi

My code uses a resource that can be described as a pointer; I'll use a `void` pointer here for simplicity. The resource must be closed after the computation with it finishes, so the `Control.Exception.bracket` function is a natural choice to make sure the code won't leak if an error occurs:

```hs
run :: (Ptr () -> IO a) -> IO a
run action = bracket acquireResource closeResource action
-- no eta reduction for clarity
```

The downside of this pattern is that the resource will always be closed after `action` completes. AFAIU this means that it isn't possible to do something like

```hs
cont <- run $ \ptr -> do
  a <- someAction ptr
  return (\x -> otherActionUsingResource ptr a x)
cont ()
```

The resource will already be close by the time `cont` is executed. Now my approach is to use a ForeignPtr instead:

```hs
run' :: (ForeignPtr () -> IO a) -> IO a
run' action = do
  ptr <- acquireResource
  foreignPtr <- newForeignPtr closeResourceFunPtr ptr
  action foreignPtr
```

Now it *seems* that this is roughly equivalent to the first version, minor typing differences and resource closing latency aside. However, I do wonder whether this is true, or if I miss something. Can some error conditions can lead to different outcomes with those two versions? Are ForeignPtr safe to use in this way?

Comment: I think this is the entire purpose of ForeignPtr, no?

Comment: @user253751 Thank you, that's reassuring; it probably is. The code is for a library in active use, so I want to make sure that I won't break other people's code with this change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do this, I'd recommend avoiding that `run'`, which makes it look like you're going to close the resource. Do something like this instead.

```
acquire :: IO (ForeignPtr ())
acquire action = mask $ \unmask -> do
  ptr <- unmask acquireResource
  newForeignPtr closeResourceFunPtr ptr
```

As Carl pointed out in a comment, it's important that exceptions be masked between acquiring the resource and installing the finalizer to close it; otherwise an asynchronous exception could be delivered in between and cause a resource leak.

The challenge with anything of this sort is that you're leaving it up to the user and/or garbage collector to make sure the resource gets freed. The original `Ptr`-based code made the lifespan explicit. Now it's not. Many people believe that explicit lifespans are better for critical resources. What `ForeignPtr` gives you, automatic finalization by the GC, these people consider poor design. So think carefully! Is this a cheap resource (like a little bit of `malloc`ed memory) that you just want to free eventually? Or is it something expensive (like a file descriptor) that you really want to be sure about?

---

Side note: `Ptr ()` and `ForeignPtr ()` aren't very idiomatic. Usually the type argument should be a Haskell type representing whatever is being pointed to.

Comment: I'd want to be a little careful about async exceptions there. `newForeignPtr` allocates, so unmasked async exceptions can cause it to abort the thread after allocating but before registering the finalizer.

Comment: @Carl, I think I fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, that looks good to me now